# How to add language tag to cffeed that creates RSS output?

Tags: coldfusion, rss, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-11

I am using `<cffeed>` to create an RSS feed for a website. I have looked at the RSS 2.0 specification and can see that there is an element called `<language>` which can be used to define the language of an item in the feed.

However, I am unable to get `<cffeed>` to add this element. Looking that CF Docs here https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-f/cffeed.html I cannot see `language` listed as a column name in the table where it shows how CF column names map across to Atom and RSS element names.

Is there any way to add it? Does CF just not support it for some odd reason?

Comment: It looks like `DC_LANGUAGE` covers some of this. I am thinking that it makes more sense to add the language to the article rather than the whole feed.

Comment: You should be able to add it to each item in the feed, just like you would a link and description

Comment: Where did you find that the `<language>` element can be added to each individual item?  Everything I see has it defined only for the entire channel. Which is what `<cffeed>` seems to do.

Comment: @Miguel-F I guess I assumed it because in an RSS feed I have items from different locales mixed together. It seems very inflexible that I can't differentiate an article for the Chinese locale to one for the US locale - even if they are both in English. Creating a new RSS channel per locale is too onerous I think.